# Haskell equivalent of -rectypes

Tags: haskell

What is the GHC equivalent of OCaml's -rectypes for allowing recursive types? I don't see one in the documentation. Is it a hidden feature?

Comment: All definitions in Haskell are recursive. Try "no switch at all".

Comment: @n.m. OCaml allows equirecursive types, which would be Haskell's equivalent of `type T a = T -> a` and similar

Comment: @jozefg looked it up. Wow. Does it really make sense? Usually such a recursive type == a coding error.

Comment: Haskell doesn't allow that.  It's not clear allowing it is a good thing.  Yes, it makes certain recursive  structures easier, but it can also easily mask type errors.

Comment: @n.m. "Coding error" might be a bit strong. It just means you can omit newtype constructors (or pattern matches whose only pattern matches the only newtype constructor).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't one unfortunately, all recursion must go through a data type. However, if you're willing to put up with a bit of headache you can still write recursive types pretty easily.

```
 newtype RecArr b a = RecArr {unArr :: RecArr b a -> b}

 unfold = unArr
 fold   = RecArr
```

Now we can `fold` and `unfold` our `RecArr` to unfold our recursion to our hearts content. This is a little painful because it's manual, but completely workable. As a demonstration, here's the y combinator written using `fold` and `unfold`.

```
 y f = (\x -> f (unfold x x)) $ fold (\x -> f (unfold x x))

 factorial f n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n-1)

 main = print (y factorial 5) -- prints 120
```

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince There isn't... Haskell doesn't support recursion at the type level since it significantly complicates an already very complex type inference/checking algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is none. All recursion has to go through nominal types. That is, you have to define a data type.